# How to upgrade my browser on 10.6.8

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, snow-leopard, upgrade

These are the specs of my mac book, currently running Snow Leopard `10.6.8`.  I'm trying to upgrade my browser, as Gmail says it's out of date, and I can't access the playlist on amazon prime.

I am not sure how to upgrade my browser.  Can anyone help?

**Hardware Overview:**

```
  Model Name:   MacBook
  Model Identifier: MacBook1,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core Duo
  Processor Speed:  1.83 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 2 MB
  Memory:   1.5 GB
  Bus Speed:    667 MHz
  Boot ROM Version: MB11.0061.B03
  SMC Version (system): 1.4f12
  Sudden Motion Sensor:
  State:    Enabled
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried twice to download Chrome, which claims it can operate on 10.6.8, but once I try to open it, it says it can't work on my mac

Comment: Yup, Chrome does not work on 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on which browser you are using...  I would recommend not using Safari on `10.6.8`, since it is unsupported by Apple at this point, and the older versions of Safari have known compatibility / security issues.

The best way to "upgrade" would just be to install a third party browser (Chrome or FireFox, which I linked to below) and those issues should go away.

To clarify, Safari is a fine browser on later versions of OS X; specifically ones that Apple still releases security patches for.

---

### Safari

On Snow Leopard, Safari cannot be upgraded past version `5.1.10.` [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history)

### FireFox

It appears that you can install the latest version of FireFox, according to the [system requirements for FireFox 37](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/37.0.2/system-requirements/) page on mozilla.org

### Google Chrome

Google Chrome's official download page says that the latest version runs on `10.6.x` [Google Chrome Download Page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade Safari beyond 5.1.10 on Snow Leopard.

At the moment, if you want a modern browser, your only option is [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). Safari on Snow Leopard is too outdated and many pages refuse to work (like youtube). Chrome does not work (I've tried it), despite Google claiming on their page that it should work on 10.6.8.

I've tried a number of other alternative browsers like Vivaldi, Midori, Pale Moon, QupZilla, Opera etc. and none of them support Snow Leopard.

Comment: Looks like Chrome no longer supports OS X 10.8 and below.

Comment: Yup, they have updated their page, you now need 10.9 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I am still using an old Macbook 1.1 as well. This cannot be upgraded past Snow Leopard. Safari works but there are a lot of issues with it that I have given up the gas on it.  Chrome no longer works and Firefox now is no longer supported (So much for their open web mantra).  The only option that I can find is Sea Monkey.  It works but there are issues with it.  Videos in social media sites like Facebook don't always play. It can crash, but remember Sea Monkey is a browser suite of software products not just a browser. So the best option is to make sure you have very little open in the background. Also keep in mind your Mac is around 10 years old.  That is a long time for a free lunch. So bear in mind to upgrade your Mac soon.  It doesn't have to be the latest and greatest. There are still a lot of macs second hand that can run Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Although unsupported google chrome is working fine on my mac book pro with 10.6.8, I've used opera also and have had good results. And I've had no issues yet with my safari other than inadvertently deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)running on imac 24 inch late 2006. 32 bit bios 64 bit 2.16 core 2 duo. It is March 2018. Warning says it is not updated any longer, but it did install because of the chromium project.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox works up to version 48. Older versions can be found at [the Mozilla FTP archive](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still running a MacBook 1.1 on Snow Leopard. I loaded mampro\spyder browser with 512Mb ram; logicExpress9 after adding 1gbRam, gnuEmacs, Arduino -- all good!

2020!

macappleUnix!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/310698)

Answer (score -1):

Sea monkey, works great on snow leopard and has many add ons, irc chat, email, etc..

Answer (score -3):

the latest chrome version that works on 32 bit hardware is Google Chrome 38.0.2125.101